# AngularJS - $scope itself undefined in Controllers after calling a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, scope

at the moment I am doing an project that provides a website with different links (using AngularJS routing). One of them should be hidden if a person isn't an administrator. The persons login and the information (if they are logged in and if they are admiistrator) gets stored in Cookies. So basically this is the layout of the page.

```
<body ng-app="Main">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#/!" class="active">Send SMS</a></li> //main-view
        <li><a href="#!edit" ng-show="isAdmin">Edit Groups</a></li> //admin-view
        <li><a href="#!logout">Log out</a></li>
   </ul>
<div ng-view></div>
```

and this is the javascript/angularjs part:

```
var app = angular.module('Main', ["ngRoute"]);

        //Controller for the admin-View
        app.controller('adminCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) 
        {                
            $scope.isAdmin = checkAdmin(); 
            console.log($scope.isAdmin);
             //many calls/functions here ($ajax etc..)
         }]);

        //Controller for the main-View
        app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) 
        {
            $scope.isAdmin = checkAdmin(); 
            //many calls/functions here ($ajax etc..)
         }]);
```

When I run the page and login I get to the main-view. If I output the value of $scope.isAdmin, I get the right value. But if I try to do something on the page, like clicking a button (so calling a function) the Console output is undefined and I get an error saying that I can't set property isAdmin of undefined.

Example function on button call:

```
$scope.sendSms = function(){
       $.ajax({
            url: 'sendSms.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {text: $scope.Text},
            success: function (response) 
            {
                  $scope.Text = "";
                  $scope.showSuccessSend = true;
                  $scope.$apply();               
             },
             error: function () 
             {
                   $scope.showFailSend = true;
             }
        });           
 };
```

I've played around for quite a long time now, tried using $rootScope etc., but the scope is always undefined. Please help me find the problem why the $scope "doesn't stay defined".
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: where is you checkAdmin function defined?

Comment: in the controller itself. It's a function that makes an ajax call and returns true or false depending on the response (from ajax)

Comment: Where are using ng-controller in your code?

Comment: I am not, I provide them with routing like this:

Comment: app.config(function($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider
                .when("/", {
                    templateUrl : "main.php",
                    controller: "mainCtrl"   
                }) .......

Comment: Why are you using scope.apply ?

Comment: So the view (GUI however) gets updated. In this case $scope.Text becomes empty and the success filed is shown.

Comment: Why are you loading a php file on your templateUrl?

Comment: @Vivz - because this pages contains the view (it's mixed html/php)

Comment: I think then it should be phtml files though I dont know if that will make much difference

Comment: What is checkAdmin() doing? Why don't you make use ng-click on buttons and inside there set thee value of ng-show

Comment: @Viviz - it is doing an ajax request and on success it compares the response with a value and returns true or false. Otherwise (on error) it simply logs error in the console for now.

Comment: what do you mean by the ng-click thing?

Answer (score 0):

Found the mistake. Controller reloaded on ajax call because I accidentally used variable name two times. Still, thank you all for your time :)